# Что должно попадать в коммит?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gitignore

Я пользуюсь Eclipse и Egit для работы с Git. Каждый раз, когда я делаю коммит, мне предлагается выбрать из файлов которые нужно закоммитить. Часть файлов уже выбраны, а часть нет. Из выбранных файлов мне Eclipse обычно предлагает закоммитить все измененные `java` файлы а также некоторые `class` файлы и некоторые другие. Насколько я понимаю `class` файлы генерируются автоматически и по идее их коммитить не обязательно так же как и `jar` файлы. Но Eclipse мне регулярно предлагает их включать в коммит.

Подскажите как поступать в этом случае? Надо ли включать в коммит файлы с расширением `class`, `jar` и другие?

Comment: Нет, все, что генерируется программой, в репозиторий влючать не нужно. Скорее всего, корректный файл `.gitignore` решит ваши проблемы.

Comment: то есть если я пишу androd приложение то я должен коммитить только java и  xml файлы разметки и стилей?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если для соответствующего class файла у вас есть java файл, то включать class файл нет никакого смысла. Другое дело, что иногда у Вас есть только class файл, тогда наверное его стоит включить. Аналогично и с jar файлами. Если этот jar - продукт компиляции Вашего кода - нет смысла его включать. Если это сторонняя библиотека - возможно есть, а может проще просто правильно настроить maven/gradle, что бы он сам все умел вытянуть.

Что бы git не предлагал включать ненужные файлы, их нужно добавить в список исключений - в файл `.gitignore`.

В целом, в коммиты нужно включать то, что нужно для компиляции. Сторонний человек должен спулить репозиторий, открыть его в эклипсе и просто нажать "скомпилируй".

Comment: а писать в gitignore надо руками или можно как то отметить игнорируемые файлы?

Comment: я обычно пишу ручками - там ничего сложного. К примеру, что бы исключить class файлы, нужно добавить строку *.class

Есть готовый "генератор" подобный файлов - https://www.gitignore.io/

Для андроида предлагает такой файл https://www.gitignore.io/api/android (скачайте и сохраните под именем .gitignore в корне проекта и закомитье его).
Файл вполне достаточный для большинства проектов.

Answer (score -1):

[Предложенный KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418866/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82/418868#comment422161_418868) инструмент для генерации .gitignore-файлов [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) предлагает следующий файл для [сочетания [java]+[eclipse]](https://www.gitignore.io/api/java,eclipse):

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io

### Java ###
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*


### Eclipse ###
*.pydevproject
.metadata
.gradle
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.settings/
.loadpath

# Eclipse Core
.project

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# JDT-specific (Eclipse Java Development Tools)
.classpath

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# sbteclipse plugin
.target

# TeXlipse plugin
.texlipse
```