# .gitignore не работает в Eclipse / Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore

Я использую `Eclipse` и плагин `Egit` для работы с системой контроля версий. [Я слышал что в файл `.gitignore` надо записывать все файлы и папки которые не должны попадать в коммит.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418866/) Но как бы я ни пытался, ничего не выходит. Например я хочу чтобы файлы с раcширением `class` не попадали в коммит. Пишу в gitignore

```
*.class
```

Или хочу чтоб папка `bin` и ее содержимое не попали в коммит, пишу так:

```
bin/
```

Но при попытке сделать коммит вижу что все эти файлы по-прежнему попадают в коммит. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: оффтоп, конечно, но я бы рекомендовал работать с Git через консоль. Это надежнее и возможностей больше.

Answer (score 1):

Есть у него такой странный глюк. Причём на разных проектах одни и те же `.gitignore` он может воспринимать совершенно по-разному, в зависимости от фазы луны :) Помогает изменение глобальных настроек самого git. Не для всех случаев сгодится, но у меня так (Linux, умолчания для CDT):

```
~/.gitconfig

...
[core]
    excludesfile = /home/dunduk/.gitexcludes
```

И:

```
~/.gitexcludes

Debug
Release
/Debug
/Release

.*
/.*

*.o
*.d
/*.o
/*.d

*.log
*.out
*.ini
/*.log
/*.out
/*.ini
```

Причём все маски повторяются дважды, со слэшем и без. Иначе Eclipse может переставать их видеть, причём тут никакой закономерности проследить пока не получилось. В этом каталоге видит, в другом то же самое - нет... А так  вроде работает всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Очень сильно подозреваю, что у вас попадают в новый коммит те файлы `.class`, которые уже отслеживаются Git. Их нужно явным образом перестать отслеживать.

**Кратко готовое решение.**

Аргумент `--cached` обязателен! Не пропустите!

```
# Убираем файлы по маске расширения
git rm --cached *.class
# Убираем папки
git rm -r --cached bin #-r значит рекурсивно
# Потом всё сохраняем в новом коммите.
git commit -m'untracked .class files'
```

**Подробная инструкция в этом вопросе**: [Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432432/181472)